# Charts/graphs in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts

How to initialize a chart with data in MS Access VBA? Eventually I found a suggestion [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/create-chart-vba-t1530514.html) which with a bit of modification kept intellisense happy and resulted in this code:

```
Dim objchart As Chart

Dim arrData(3, 1) As Double

arrData(0, 0) = 1
arrData(1, 0) = 1
arrData(2, 0) = 1
arrData(3, 0) = 1

arrData(0, 1) = 1
arrData(1, 1) = 1
arrData(2, 1) = 1
arrData(3, 1) = 1

Set objchart = Me.Chart1

With objchart
    .ChartTitle = "test"
    .ChartType = acChartLine
    .ChartValues = arrData
End With
```

But this throws

> Compile error: Type mismatch

on the line

```
    .ChartValues = arrData
```

I have tried it as "row-first" (arrData(1, 3)) and also just passing in a single array (arrData(3)). These both result in the same type mismatch error. While the intellisense is telling me that Chart1 exists, and that .ChartValues is a valid field, it doesn't tell me what kind of object it is expecting. I have googled extensively on this and come up empty. The best references I could find for Access VBA were [Building VBA Apps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615927114) and [this](http://www.mvps.org/access/) but neither go into detail on Charts or ChartObjects.

Obviously I'd like to get past this type mismatch error. Even better would be if someone can give me some general advice on how to go about this when the closest thing to a language [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access) is silent on the part of the language you need.

Comment: Use the object browser to view the details of the chart object. Its no longer supported in newer versions of access (so my research suggests). The best way to see what it thinks it ought to be receiving is the object browser.

Comment: I can't get past 'Method or data member not found' compile error for .ChartValues.

Comment: Thanks Doug, very helpful. .ChartValues appears to accept a String. I have got a chart working with .RowSource as a table name, .ChartAxis as a table field name, and .ChartValues as another table field name. But there doesn't seem to be a way to stop it treating the ChartAxis field as a category to group over and using a sum function for the group operation. Ideally one could populate the chart directly but I can't see how to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. First, create a new table and add some data:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rec As Recordset
  Dim tbl As DAO.TableDef

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set tbl = db.CreateTableDef("tbl")

  With tbl
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("first", dbInteger)
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("second", dbInteger)
  End With

  db.TableDefs.Append tbl
  db.TableDefs.Refresh

  Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("tbl")

  rec.AddNew
  rec("first").Value = 0
  rec("second").Value = 2
  rec.Update

  rec.AddNew
  rec("first").Value = 1
  rec("second").Value = 2
  rec.Update

  rec.AddNew
  rec("first").Value = 2
  rec("second").Value = 2
  rec.Update

  rec.AddNew
  rec("first").Value = 3
  rec("second").Value = 2
  rec.Update

  Set rec = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Second, graph that data by referencing the new table:

```
Private Sub command0_click()

  Dim objchart As Chart
  Set objchart = Me.Chart1

  With objchart
    .ChartTitle = "tbl: second ~ first"
    .RowSource = "tbl"
    .ChartAxis = "first"
    .ChartValues = "second"
  End With

End Sub
```